# R: Match number of decimal places to neighboring value

Tags: r, rounding

I have the following dataframe:

```
SigFig <-structure(list(SampleID = c("54816", "54820", "54825", "54829", 
                            "54833", "54837", "M204", "M206", "M214", "M220", "M222", "N145", 
                            "N146", "P61", "P62", "P73"), `Chloride mg/L` = c("3.67", "2.79", 
                                                                              "2.49", "4.62", "4.98", "2.75", "42.7", "18.6", "29.4", "16.1", 
                                                                              "7.46", "0.28", "5.23", "11.8", "2.31", "2.85"), `Chloride SD` = c(0.0138, 
                                                                                                                                                 0.00759, 0.00854, 0.00982, 0.0315, 0.00697, 0.412, 0.173, 0.26, 
                                                                                                                                                 0.296, 0.0858, NA, NA, 0.158, 0.0256, 0.0314)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

All of the chloride concentration values have been reduced to 3 significant figures. My goal is to have the standard deviation values be rounded to the same number of decimal places as the corresponding concentration.  I've tried the following:

```
# Round sd values to match reported concentration
for(i in SigFig$`Chloride SD`){
  Cl.SD <- if_else(SigFig$`Chloride mg/L` >= 10, as.character(sprintf('%.1f',SigFig$`Chloride SD`)),
                    if_else(SigFig$`Chloride mg/L` >= 1&SigFig$`Chloride mg/L` <10, as.character(sprintf('%.2f',SigFig$`Chloride SD`)),
                            as.character(sprintf('%.3f',SigFig$`Chloride SD`))))
  assign(paste0("", i), Cl.SD)
}
SigFig$`Chloride SD` <- Cl.SD
```

With the results:

```
   SampleID `Chloride mg/L` `Chloride SD`
   <chr>    <chr>           <chr>        
 1 54816    3.67            0.0          
 2 54820    2.79            0.0          
 3 54825    2.49            0.0          
 4 54829    4.62            0.0          
 5 54833    4.98            0.0          
 6 54837    2.75            0.0          
 7 M204     42.7            0.4          
 8 M206     18.6            0.2          
 9 M214     29.4            0.3          
10 M220     16.1            0.3          
11 M222     7.46            0.1          
12 N145     0.28            NA           
13 N146     5.23            NA           
14 P61      11.8            0.2          
15 P62      2.31            0.0          
16 P73      2.85            0.0
```

It seems as though the code always selects the first condidtion, as all the values are rounded to the first decimal place.  I've tried changing the loop to `for(i in SigFig[i,3)` but get an error with this approach.  The desired output would be:

```
SampleID    Chloride mg/L   Chloride SD
54816       3.67            0.01
54820       2.79            0.01
54825       2.49            0.01
54829       4.62            0.01
54833       4.98            0.03
54837       2.75            0.01
M204        42.7            0.4
M206        18.6            0.2
M214        29.4            0.3
M220        16.1            0.3
M222        7.46            0.09
N145        0.28            
N146        5.23    
P61         11.8            0.02
P62         2.31            0.03
P73         2.85            0.03
```

Comment: Are those numbers really rounded to those number of decimal places? Or is that just the display setting for your `data.frame`/`tibble`? By default, R uses the same number of decimal places for all elements of a vector (see, for example, `c(1.2, 1.22, 1)`).

Comment: And are you trying to limit to a number of decimal places or number of significant figures?

Comment: @ A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Those are the actual rounded values.

Comment: @da11an 7  I am trying to limit the number of decimal places.  I don't want to report error values beyond the last decimal place of the measured concentration.  For instance, if the measured value is 4.56 and the standard deviation was 0.21687, I would want to round the sd to 0.22 (2 decimal places regardless of sig figures)

Comment: @pbliznik, can you please edit your question with the result of `dput` on the `head` of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming your initial table `SigFig`, the following code will achieve your goal:

```
library(dplyr)

SigFig %>%
  mutate(
    decimals = sapply(my_data$`Chloride mg/L`, function(.x) nchar(strsplit(.x, "\\.")[[1]][2])),
    `Chloride SD` = round(`Chloride SD`, decimals)
  ) %>%
  select(-decimals)
```

How this works:

1. Create a new column `decimals` that gets the number of decimal places by splitting the the mg/L column at the decimal place and counting the number of characters in the second part.
2. Round the SD column to the places in the decimals column.
3. Drop the decimals column because you don't need it anymore.

Comment: That worked!  That approach had occurred to me but I couldn't figure out how to implement it.  Thanks so much!